# Spring-boot & Java FindById returning null instead of the number

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Could someone tell me why my code isn't able to find the Id for each person? My code is creating a new row in SQL every time I update already inputted person information because it is not finding the Id. 
I am using an older version of Spring-Boot and I know in newer versions findById has become optional... is this causing an issue in my older version?

Here is my repository code:

```html
@Transactional
public interface BrokerRepository extends CrudRepository<Broker,Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

    Broker save(Broker entity);

    Broker findById(Long id);

    void delete(Broker entity);

    List<Broker> findAll();

    List<Broker> findByBrokerDetailContaining(String brokerDetail);
    List<Broker> findByAccountNameContaining(String accountName);
    List<Broker> findByEpicBrokerCodeContaining(String epicBrokerCode);

    List<Broker> findByStatus(String prospect);

//    List<Broker> findByExpiration(LocalDate licenseExpiration);
}
```

Here is my controller

```html
    @RequestMapping(value="/edit/{id}")
    public String editbroker(Model model, @PathVariable("id") Long id){
        Broker existing= brokerRepository.findById(id);
        model.addAttribute("broker",existing);
        return "brokerProfile";
    }



    @RequestMapping(value="/saveBroker")
    @ResponseBody
    public JSONObject saveBroker(Model model, @ModelAttribute(value="broker") Broker broker)
    {
        Boolean saved=false;
        JSONObject response=new JSONObject();
        Broker brokerBeforeUpdate=brokerRepository.findById(broker.getId());
        if (brokerBeforeUpdate!=null && !brokerBeforeUpdate.getStatus().equals("active") && broker.getStatus().equals("active"))
            broker.setOnboardedDate(LocalDate.now());
        else if (!broker.getStatus().equals("active"))
            broker.setOnboardedDate(null);
        try{
            brokerBeforeUpdate=brokerRepository.save(broker);
            saved=true;
            response.put("id",broker.getId());

        }catch (DataAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.put("error",e.getLocalizedMessage());
            response.put("cause",e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        response.put("success",saved);
        return response;
    }
```

and here is my XML:

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
 <artifactId>Portal</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>
 <name>Portal</name>
 <description>Portal</description>
  <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.dblock.waffle</groupId>
   <artifactId>waffle-spring-security3</artifactId>
   <version>1.8.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security.kerberos</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-kerberos-web</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-java8time</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <!-- flying saucer pdf -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
   <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
   <version>9.1.4</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- jxls simple excel -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
   <artifactId>jxls</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.3</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
   <artifactId>jxls-poi</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.14</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
   <artifactId>jxls-jexcel</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.6</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.8.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.metawidget.modules</groupId>
   <artifactId>metawidget-all</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>

  <!--<dependency>-->
  <!--<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
  <!--<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>-->
  <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
  <!--</dependency>-->
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
     <executable>true</executable>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

HTML form:

```html
    <div id="rootwizard" class="container" th:with="brokerEndpoint = ${broker.id == null ? '/addBroker' : '/saveBroker'}">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" th:action="${brokerEndpoint}" method="post" th:object="${broker}" class="tab-content">
            <h4>Broker Onboarding Info</h4>
            <br/>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">Broker Detail</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="brokerDetail" th:field="*{brokerDetail}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">Account Name</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="accountName" th:field="*{accountName}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">Parent Account</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="parentAccount" th:field="*{parentAccount}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>

                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">Physical Zip</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="physicalZip" th:field="*{physicalZip}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">Date Appointed</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="dateAppt" th:field="*{dateAppt}" class="form-control date"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">Phone</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="phone" th:field="*{phone}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">Website</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="website" th:field="*{website}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">Main Agency Contact</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="mainAgencyContact" th:field="*{mainAgencyContact}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">FEIN #</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="feinNo" th:field="*{feinNo}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8" style="margin-left:5.27rem;">
                            <label>Appointment Paperwork Sent
                                <input type="checkbox" id="apptPaperworkSent" th:field="*{apptPaperworkSent}" class="flexFit"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8" style="margin-left:13rem;">
                            <label>License Received
                                <input type="checkbox" id="licenseRecd" th:field="*{licenseRecd}" class="flexFit"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">License Effective</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="licenseEffective" th:field="*{licenseEffective}" class="form-control date"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">License Expiration</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="licenseExpiration" th:field="*{licenseExpiration}" class="form-control date"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8" style="margin-left:8rem;">
                            <label>E&amp;O Dec. Page Received
                                <input type="checkbox" id="eoDecPageRecd" th:field="*{eoDecPageRecd}" class="flexFit"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">E&amp;O Effective Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="eoEffectiveDate" th:field="*{eoEffectiveDate}" class="form-control date"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">E&amp;O Expiration Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="eoExpirationDate" th:field="*{eoExpirationDate}" class="form-control date"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8" style="margin-left:4.5rem;">
                            <label class="flexFit">W9 Received
                                <input type="checkbox" id="w9Recd" th:field="*{w9Recd}" class="flexFit"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">W9 Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="w9Date" th:field="*{w9Date}" class="form-control date"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">Status</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="status" th:field="*{status}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">Onboarded Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="onboardedDate" th:field="*{onboardedDate}" class="form-control date"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8 check-div" style="margin-left:6.85rem;">
                            <label>Agent Agreement Received
                                <input type="checkbox" id="agentAgreementRecd" th:field="*{agentAgreementRecd}" class="flexFit"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8 check-div" style="margin-left:6.85rem;">
                            <label>1099 Required
                                <input type="checkbox" id="x1099required" th:field="*{x1099required}" class="flexFit"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8 check-div" style="margin-left:6rem;">
                            <label style="margin-left: 30px;" >Contact Sheet Received
                                <input type="checkbox" id="contactSheetRecd" th:field="*{contactSheetRecd}" class="flexFit"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">Contact Sheet Date</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="contactSheetDate" th:field="*{contactSheetDate}" class="form-control date"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">Description</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="description" th:field="*{description}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">Office Paid</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="officePaid" th:field="*{officePaid}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">formerBrokerName</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="formerBrokerName" th:field="*{formerBrokerName}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">E&amp;O Renewal Follow-up 1</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="eoRenewalFollowUp1" th:field="*{eoRenewalFollowUp1}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8 check-div" style="margin-left:7rem;">
                            <label >E&amp;O Follow-up 1 Complete
                                <input type="checkbox" id="eoFollowUp1Complete" th:field="*{eoFollowUp1Complete}" class="flexFit"/>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">E&amp;O Renewal Follow-up 2</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="eoRenewalFollowUp2" th:field="*{eoRenewalFollowUp2}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>

                    <div class="row">
                        <label class="col-sm-6 col-xs-4 text-right">Billing Zip Code</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-8">
                            <input type="text" id="billingZipCode" th:field="*{billingZipCode}" class="form-control"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                </div> <!--end of right column-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="text-right" sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
                        <input id="submitButton"  type="submit" value="Save" name="save" class="btn tangramColor txt finish" data-loading-text="Saved!" disabled="true"/><br/>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're missing `@Repository`

Comment: @Andronicus added it, but it  didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Just to be sure, have you checked that you are receiving the ID and the ID actually exists?

Comment: @epsilonmajorquezero the ID is generated automatically when you add a new entry, by SQL. Also my url with the user ID pulls the correct information so the ID definitely exists. The probelm is the findById is not receiving the id...and I am not sure why. It shows as Null.

Comment: @Stacie "findById is not receiving the id." With that you mean that broker.getId() is returning Null? Because then you should be check what are you sending "/saveBroker"

broker.getId()

Comment: @epsilonmajorquezero yes that is what I mean, broker.getId() returns null. So you are saying something is wrong with my controller function?

Comment: @epsilonmajorquezero my getId() function works in other functions, so I am not sure why it's just this one method that it is returning null for. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you tried actually debugging to see what the incoming broker object has? My first suspicion is that it won't have an Id.

Comment: Basically I see nothing wrong with the code you posted so probably the error is somewhere else :)

Comment: Could it be my html form?

Comment: That would be my initial thought. Check out if the broker object you are receiving has an Id by setting a break point with the debugger here Boolean saved=false; and inspecting the broker object. I bet the Id will be null.

Comment: It is null, that is what I need help figuring out how to fix it. Clearly it is not being called correctly if the function works elsewhere but not here.